# Parrot with no internet connection

Tags: linux

I've been "tuning" my parrot os with bspwm, when I launched it it all worked, only the wifi connection wasn't working. In the directory **/etc/resolv.conf** was clear. I typed `sudo nano /etc/resolve.conf`
Anf it only shows me an empty GNU. I typed

> ```
>   GNU nano 5.4
> ```
>
> nameserver 8.8.8.8

But still don't work. Can I get some help? I'm new at this.

Comment: If you're new don't use Parrot. Use a friendlier distribution such as Mint

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions:

1. If you don't have wireless driver or firmware, install one through ethernet or USB flash.
2. Install dhcp client and server.
3. Install network manager.
   If you are new, network configuration tools may be better than configuring manually. The software you need depend on your distribution.